# Hanburger menu just stopped working and no longer opens, it also adds an # to the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, hamburger-menu

on my site my hanburger menu just stopped working and no longer opens, it also adds an # to the URL when you click on the mobile version of it?

Not sure why it just all the sudden stopped working but I tried disabling all the plugins and turned them on one by one.

- Tried removing the code I entered a couple weeks back.
- Deleted the recent CSS code I added to make mobile version show properly
- I also removed any custom css that could affect this hamburger menu and no luck.

Anyone have an idea why this is not working right now and what my next few steps would be to fix it?

Here is the site: https://rocketpilots.com the hamburger menu used to work fine yesterday and then woke up today to it not working anymore. Anyone have a fix for this issue, it is not plugins or custom css because tried both those options and no luck? I am pretty sure it is a javascipt issue just not sure exactly what?

Code for header.php:

```
    <div class="fusion-header-sticky-height"></div>
     <div class="fusion-header">
    <div class="fusion-row">
      <?php avada_logo(); ?>
      <?php avada_main_menu(); ?>
       <div class="logo_text"><h3 style="font-size:11px !important;color:#1592CE !important;"><a style="font-size:11px !important;color:#1592CE !important;" href="https://rocketpilots.com">Digital Marketing</a></h3></div>
```

Free Consultation

Please any assistance would be greatly appreciated, just cannot figure out why Hamburger menu stopped working, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Use your developer console.  Load your site.  Note the javascript error? That error is preventing other script(s) from running on your site, including your **hamburger** menu (not hanburger).

Comment: `TypeError: jQuery(...)[0].nextSibling is null`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null`

Comment: jQuery does not have a method `nextSibling`, and even if it had one, it would have to be called using brackets.

Comment: Where would I locate this in my files, I went through header.php as well as functions.php and had no luck finding these things so I can remove them, where would I find these items or lines of javascript in my work so I can remove them that way it does not cause this issue, please let me know where I would locate this information. I see it in the console, I am just not sure how to remove said lines of code or how to find it, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this code from inside the `<script>` tag:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('p strong')[0].nextSibling.remove('.');
});
```

This is causing the error seen in the console; whatever it's attempting to target doesn't exist in the document. This snippet also has a  `jQuery(document).ready(){}` contained inside of another one, which is redundant.

Comment: `jQuery('p strong')[0].nextSibling.remove('.');` should probably be `jQuery('p strong').first().next().remove('.');` https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: Where would I locate this in my files, I went through header.php as well as functions.php and had no luck finding these things so I can remove them, where would I find these items or lines of javascript in my work so I can remove them that way it does not cause this issue, please let me know where I would locate this information. I see it in the console, I am just not sure how to remove said lines of code or how to find it, please let me know. Thanks!